# Multiple $http.get request responses get swapped. Is there a solution?

Tags: angularjs, http, angularjs-scope

I have a page running as an angular js application that makes multiple requests to different APIs on the same server to get different set of values that are then rendered on the page. But, every once in a while, say one of three refreshes, I observe that the response of one request is getting assigned to another and hence the UI is breaking.

Say I am requesting 2 URLs :

```
$http.get('/req1').success(function(response1){
     /*some scope assignment*/
}).error(function(error1){});

$http.get('/req2').success(function(response2){
     /*some scope assignment*/
}).error(function(error2){});
```

Now weirdly every 3 or 4th refresh. The `response2` is getting sent as a parameter to the success callback of `/req1` and `response1` is getting sent as a parameter to the success callback of `/req2`. As a result a my UI is breaking down whenever that happens. 
How do I fix it?

Comment: I've never observed this happening.... what a strange bug

Comment: I don't get it. `response1` is the parameter for `/req1` success function.. do you mean `response2`?

Comment: @Gustav :You are right. Thank for correcting

Comment: I guess that the error will be elsewhere ... either on server-side or in the code which is not shown in your sample. You can try server response by repeatedly calling url `/req1` in your browser

Comment: @jackOfAll The problem is most likely in your scope assignments. I've had projects with multiple $http requests with $timeout in the same controller/scope and in different controllers without issues. If you could post the whole code it would be easier to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of your issues is very unlikely to be either the browser or angular re-assigning the response of one request to a different request - that would break a lot more than just your UI!

Without seeing more of your code and having a bit more context, it's impossible to say what exactly *is* happening, but it's not what you have described in the question.

My advice is to make heavy use of the chrome debugger tools, the network tab, and `console.log` and see what you can find out. If you make progress, feel free to update the question.

Comment: Okay.. Will take that approach and update the answer if I make any progress.

Comment: Actually I just checked using the Chrome debugger tools. Both the requests are receiving the same response once in a few refreshes. And one set of scope variables get wrongly updated and my UI breaks.

Comment: So then your server is sending the wrong response - you should look into the server side code.